# converting to&from OpenCV cv::Mat, NSImage

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opencv

There's an article describing how to do this  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563356/nsimage-to-cvmat-and-vice-versa), that seems to have worked for other people but it does not compile for me.

Here's a copy of the .h file that was used:

```
//
//  NSImage+OpenCV.h
//

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface NSImage (NSImage_OpenCV) {

}

+(NSImage*)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat;
-(id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat;

@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVMat;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) cv::Mat CVGrayscaleMat;

@end
```

I'm on Xcode 4.4, using openCV 2.4.2.  The compiler errors I'm getting for the header file are 4x of the following:

`Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'cv'`

This error seems rather obvious...the header file does not define what a cv::Mat is.
So I took a guess from looking at the OpenCV 2.4 tutorial, that I needed to add

`#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`

This generated 20 other errors, where the compiler was complaining about the core.hpp file.
The first of which says:

`Semantic issue: Non-const static data member must be initialized out of line`

So my question is what am I doing wrong?  How do I get this code to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another stackoverflow Q&A (link: [How to include OpenCV in Cocoa Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810800/how-to-include-opencv-in-cocoa-application?rq=1)) had the missing piece on the undefined symbols.

To summarize:

1. The OpenCV headers have to be included before the Cocoa headers, due to a macro conflict.
2. Xcode automatically includes the cocoa headers at the top of every objective-C file (*.m, *.mm), which prevents you from adding the OpenCV headers first, as stated in point 1.
3. Xcode has a "-Prefix.pch" file that defines any code which is automatically prepended to any code.

Normally, it looks like:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

Instead, the file should be changed to look like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

So in the case of any *.cpp file, the opencv header gets added automatically.  In the case of any *.m file, the Cocoa headers are added.  And in the special case of *.mm files, they BOTH get added, and in the correct order.

Kudos to Ian Charnas and user671435 for figuring this out.

Comment: Your answer helped me to resolve most of the errors I got in xcode, but after I did what you described above, I still get one error in lsh_table.h "Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'use_speed_'". Do you know how do I get rid of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is C++ syntax. You have to give your source file the `.mm` suffix to make it Objective-C++.

Comment: I've already done this. The compiler recognizes the syntax, but not the symbols "cv" and "Mat", which are undefined.